# Use a shell variable to execute a command

Tags: bash, find

I have a unix command in a variable, it looks like this:

```
cmd="find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@"
`$cmd`
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

When I try to execute the command `$cmd` in a bash script, it won't work. However, when I copy and paste the exact same command, it does work.   Can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

I have tried putting quotes around the path, same error occurs

```
cmd="find \"/path/to/webpage\" -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@"
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

When I remove the `-type f` parameter, I get this error:

```
cmd="find /path/to/webpage | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@"
find: invalid predicate `-v'
```

That makes me think that the pipe is not being recognized.  What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Long command pipelines in shell variables should make anyone nervous.  What are you trying to do?  I recommend taking some time to read and digest [BashFAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) before taking this approach any further.

Comment: are you trying to execute the contents of a variable or assign the output of a command to a variable?  Your question says the former, but your response to Tim's answer says the latter.

Answer (score 7):

Others have already explained what to do. Let me explain what's happening here: the pipe character `|` doesn't make a pipeline as the variable is expanded, but acts like a literal character. Therefore, `find` is executed with the following arguments:

```
{"/path/to/webpage", "-type", "f", "|", "grep", "-v", ".svn", "|", ...}
```

and it interprets the `|` as a path and complains that it should have appeared before the expression (`-type f`).

Another big mistake is that you're using `` `$cmd` `` as the sole command line. If `$cmd` (i.e. `find ...`) succeeded and produced output like `rm -rf /`, it would be executed on your behalf. **Always take caution when you take data as code!**

*Improvement 1.* `find ... | grep -v ...` is a poor way to exclude something from the output: `find` will traverse whole subdirectories named `.svn`, produce the lines, only to be thrown away later. Why not tell `find` to do it directly?

```
find path -type f | grep -v .svn                # don't do this
find path -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print   # do this instead
```

*Improvement 2.* When combining `find` and `xargs`, always use `-print0` in `find` and `-0` in `xargs`:

```
find path ... -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep ...    # I'd also recommend -r
```

or you can do it entirely in `grep`:

```
grep --recursive --exclude-dir=.svn pattern path
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to execute code in a variable, you can do it using `eval`.

```
cmd="find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep something"
eval "$cmd"
```

But since you're trying to pass arguments in with `$@`, what you need here is a function

```
webgrep() {
    find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep "$@"
}
```

Note that this will have problems with any paths that include a whitespace character.  Or patterns that start with a minus.  And it will have to scan all the contents of `.svn` directories before ignoring them.  And it would be nice to handle the user accidentally passing multiple arguments (e.g. because the pattern wasn't quoted properly).  A better way is

```
webgrep() {
    find /path/to/webpage -name .svn -prune -o -type f -exec grep -e "$*" {} +
}
```

Then call it like this

```
webgrep PATTERN
```

Comment: You probably need to use `grep -e "$*"` to demote the list of command line arguments to a string and to protect against the cases where the string starts with a dash.

Comment: @Kusalananda Quite right, I've updated the last version of `webgrep` to address those concerns too.

Answer (score 1):

Try building your variable like this:

```
cmd=$(find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@)
```

or

```
cmd=`find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@`
```

Or maybe an alias would be better suited:

```
alias cmd="find /path/to/webpage -type f | grep -v .svn | xargs grep $@"
```

Comment: Thank you, using the $(command) method is what did the trick!

Comment: No problem! You caught me mid-edit, but should be fixed now.

Comment: That's not putting the code in a variable.  It's putting the output of the command in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* put code in a variable, as a rule of thumb. Use a function.

```
cmd() { 
  find /path/to/webpage -type f |
    grep -v .svn                | 
    xargs grep $@
}

cmd "$@"
```

If you do eventually end up having to put *simple* code in a variable (don't, but if you do...) then as mentioned, you can't embed things like pipes or redirections without an `eval`...and don't do that either, lol

But don't execute it in backticks, which run the commands in a subshell and replace it with the output, so that the output becomes what the parser is receiving as the command to execute:

```
$: `echo foo`
bash: foo: command not found
```